# Button Add with modal ajax

Tags: php, ajax, modal-dialog

I'm trying to add a button to add a row in a table adding the values also in a database but when i click the button it refresh my page and doesn't add any row and in my database doesn't add any values.

This is the html form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modaladdWork" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="modaladdWorkLabel">New Work</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
            <form name="formaddWork">
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container w-75">
                    <select id="roleaddWork" name="role" class="form-control" aria-label="Role" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
      <option>Direttore</option>
      <option>Vice Direttore</option>
      <option>Capo Settore</option>
      <option>Dipendente</option>
      <option>Stagista</option>
      </select>    <br>
                    <input type="number" id="yearaddWork" name="year" min="1900" class="form-control" placeholder="Year" aria-label="Year" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" id="placeaddWork" name="place" class="form-control" placeholder="Place" aria-label="Place" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                    <br />
                      <?php  
      $query = "select * from company;";
     $result=mysqli_query($connessione, $query);
      echo mysqli_error($connessione);
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){ 
     echo "<div style='float:left';><select id='companyaddWork' name='company' class='form-control' aria-label='Company' aria-describedby='basic-addon1'>"; 
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

     echo "<option>".$row["name"]."</option>";

    }
     echo "</select></div>  <div class='modal-footer'><div style='float:right';>
                <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary float-right' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalCompany'>
          Add Company
        </button>
              </div></div>";
     }
      else{
          echo "Inserisci prima una compagnia";
      }

      ?>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" id="submitaddWork" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and this the javascript code :

```
function openmodal_addWork()
        {

            $('#modaladdWork').find('.modal-title').text("Add Work row");
            $('#modaladdWork').find(':submit').text("Add");
            $('#submitaddWork').click(function() { 
                op_addWork();
            });
            $('#modaladdWork').modal('show');
        }

        function op_addWork()
        {   
            role = $('#roleaddWork').val();
            year = $('#yearaddWork').val();
            place = $('#placeaddWork').val();
            company = $('#companyaddWork').val();
            $('#modaladdWork').modal('hide');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "json/Lavoro.php",
                data: {
                    'role': role,
                    'year': year,
                    'place': place,
                    'company': company
                },
                success: function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        columns = $(button).closest('tr').find('td');
                        columns[0].innerHTML = role;
                        columns[1].innerHTML = year;
                        columns[2].innerHTML = place;
                        columns[3].innerHTML = company;
                }
            });
        }
```

and this one the file "Lavoro.php" that is in the folder "json" :

```
 <?php
 if(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest')
 {
   header("Location: ../Principale.php");
   exit();
 }

 if(!isset($_COOKIE["id"]))
 {
   $json_data = array(
'draw'            => 0,
'recordsTotal'    => 0,
'recordsFiltered' => 0,
'data'            => [],
'error'           => 'Laravel Error Handler',
          );
                  $json = json_encode($json_data);
             echo $json;
        exit();
 }   



 include("../DB.php"); //dati configurazione del database


 if(isset($_POST["role"]) && isset($_POST["year"]) && isset($_POST["place"]) && isset($_POST["company"]))
 { 
                  $role = mysqli_real_escape_string($connessione, $_POST["role"]);
             $year = mysqli_real_escape_string($connessione, $_POST["year"]);
        $place = mysqli_real_escape_string($connessione, $_POST["place"]);
   $company = mysqli_real_escape_string($connessione, $_POST["company"]);

           $result=mysqli_query($connessione,"select company_id from company where name='".$company."';");
       $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
  $comp_id=$row[0];
$eeid=$_COOKIE['id'];

   $result = mysqli_query($connessione, "INSERT into WORK_EXPERIENCE (role,year,place,company_id,user_id) VALUES ('$role','$year','$place','$comp_id,'$eeid')");

   $json_data = array(
                                //"id" => $id,
                                "result" => 1
                         );
$json = json_encode($json_data);
echo $json;
 }



 ?>
```

What i'm doing of wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. In this line :

```
 $result = mysqli_query($connessione, "INSERT into WORK_EXPERIENCE 
 (role,year,place,company_id,user_id) VALUES 
 ('$role','$year','$place','$comp_id,'$eeid')")
```

there was no summit in $comp_id.